# After destroying a prefab and then recreating the prefab, the new clone objects are not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code to spawn a spinning ball that moves left, right and falls down. The spawn point (empty object) is set about 3 units above the ground, so it will fall to the ground and move left or right. 
The problem I am facing is that after I destroy the clones of the prefab and reset it to spawn in the original position and expect it to fall to the ground and move, but it only spawns in the original position and it does not fall to the ground. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
  `

```
public class spawnLemmings : MonoBehaviour {

 //this is the number of lemmings that will spawn
 private int numLemming = 6;

 //Creating a prefab gameObject to attach the prefab to
 public GameObject prefab;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
    Spawn();
 }
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
    Reset();
 }

 void Spawn()
 {
    //A for loop to create desired number of Lemmings
    for (int i = 0; i < numLemming; i++)
    {
        //This is where the game object is being created
        prefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);


        //This sets the speed of lemming.
        //prefab.GetComponent<lemmingMovement>().speed = Random.Range(3.0f, 4.0f); ///speed = 2.0f;

        //This resets onGround to false
        //prefab.GetComponent<lemmingMovement>().OnGround();
    }
 }
 void Reset()
 {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
    {
        GameObject[] lems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Lemmings");
        foreach (GameObject lem in lems)
        {
            Destroy(lem);
        }
        Spawn();
    }
 }
}
```

`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove FixedUpdate (), I was just testing to see if that was causing the problem. my code uses Update().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

You are assigning the new object that you created to the prefab that you use to clone objects

Try this

```
//This is where the game object is being created
GameObject o = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Welcome. You can mark this question as solved by selecting this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

From the what I could gather, I am stating below -

1. I don't know how your whole code is working, but from the comments I think you should set the speed by uncommenting the code -

   ```
   //This sets the speed of lemming.
   //prefab.GetComponent<lemmingMovement>().speed = Random.Range(3.0f, 4.0f); ///speed = 2.0f;
   ```
2. If the object is a rigidbody, then check if the newly created prefabs/clones have rigidbody as well. Sometimes I forget to update my prefabs after latest change.